# What is the accuracy when firing an electron at a target?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, error-analysis, microscopy

Consider firing an electron at a target. Let the target be at a distance $d$ and the electron be travelling at a non-relativistic speed $v$. How can we estimate the *maximum* possible accuracy achievable?

My initial thoughts are to apply Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, $$\Delta x\Delta p\geq h.$$ We know that $p=mv$ so have $$m\Delta x\Delta v\geq h.$$ We could make an estimate at the uncertainty in the speed. Say if we are given a value of $100$km/s and then say that the uncertainty is about $1$km/s. Thus we can have an accuracy in the electrons position of $$\Delta x\geq \frac{h}{m\Delta v}.$$ My first problem with this is that it seems like a bit of a shrewd calculation, and also it gives the *minimum* possible accuracy.

Comment: You can find as many technical details as you like about this in textbooks on electron microscope design. In practice most electron devices stay at least two orders of magnitude (often three or more) above this physical limit. The relevant limiting effects in electron optics are of technical and not of physical in nature.

Comment: @CuriousOne - I would have considered effective source size and energy spread to be physical constraints - I may quite well be missing your distinguishing of technical vs physical though.

Comment: Well this question was one I came across on a past paper for a module that is basically a set of random questions that is designed to develop our ability to solve problems. There should be no physics beyond the classical except Heisenberg's uncertainty

Comment: This calls for a Yogi Berra quotation (it's not from him, which makes it even funnier): "In theory, theory and practice are the same, in practice they are not.". You are correct that you were expected to give the naive answer and there is nothing wrong with it. There is a slightly more theoretical answer ("squeezed states") and then there is the practical difficulty of getting electrons localized anywhere near this theoretical limit. It doesn't hurt to have heard about all of them.

Comment: @JonCuster: There are more problems, e.g. the numerical aperture of electron optics and the electrostatic interaction in beams with non-trivial beam current, especially in accelerator beams, which are many orders of magnitude away from the uncertainty principle limit.

Comment: Nice comments! Always good to know about all the different possibilities, outcomes and methods.

Comment: @CuriousOne - of course (and we have had side conversations on this before). Since you had mentioned electron microscopes, there are no space charge effects in a TEM (except perhaps with the new pulsed-laser driven short time sources). I agree that electron microscopes are far from the uncertainty principle limits, but the limits that remain are, well, physical in nature and can be described with physics. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

For some detailed analysis of the limits for electron microscopy, see:
[Viewpoint: What Are the Resolution Limits in Electron Microscopes?](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v6/82)  This is a brief review of the technology, and they summarize the recent improvements in resolution with:

"The authors estimate that the resulting resolution limit is in the range $0.50–0.8Å$, which is consistent with the best that has been achieved to date."

I've experienced these improvements over my career. At every stage there were those who said we were already at the limits, or that the next step was either too expensive, or of little value.